# Is there a way to get typed theme from useTheme() hook in react-native-paper

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

Right now I'm following the [theming](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/using-on-the-web.html) `react-native-paper` guide for custom theming. But when trying to consume the theme via the `useTheme` hook, it looks like that the response I've got as a `theme` object is not properly/fully typed and respectively I'm not able to use the object destructuring autocomplete.

```
export const LightTheme = {
  ...PaperDefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    customColor: 'green',
  },
};

<PaperProvider
  theme={
    colorScheme === "dark"
      ? { ...DarkTheme }
      : { ...LightTheme }
}
>
  <AppProvider>
    {{...}}
  </AppProvider>
</PaperProvider>
```

Here VSCode displays that the inferred type for the `theme` object is `const theme: Theme` but does not recognise the theme properties when trying the access them:

```
import { useTheme } from "react-native-paper";

const theme = useTheme();
// e.g. theme.colors is not autocompleted
```

Currently as a solution I'm wrapping the `useTheme` hook in a custom one that returns the desired `Theme` type from my typings:

```
import { useTheme as _useTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import { Theme } from "../theme";

export function useTheme(): Theme {
  const theme = _useTheme();
  return theme;
}
```

At the time of writing, I'm using version <s>5.0.0-rc.6</s> `5.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the types files show, `useTheme` has a generic parameter to support a typed object such as:

```
const myTheme = { ... };
type MyTheme = typeof myTheme;
const theme = useTheme<MyTheme>()
```

Of course, for the sake of reusability you could mix this with your provided solution:

```
import { useTheme as _useTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import { Theme } from "../theme";

export function useTheme() {
  const theme = _useTheme<Theme>();
  return theme;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Couldn't find that solution with the v5 release candidates, but it is now well documented after the official release.